# Polymer 2 TypeError on Local DOM element when Event triggered

Tags: javascript, events, polymer, dom-events, polymer-2.x

I have a search input field to receive user input and a variable-state button that responds to user input. Notice the `on-input` event on the search input.

```
<dom-module id="app-search">
    <template>
        
        <input type="search" id="searchInput" on-input="_onInput" />

        <!-- NOTE: button is set to 'disabled' when there is no value of search field -->
        <paper-button disabled>Done</paper-button>

    </template>
</dom-module>
```

In the Polymer `ready()` definition I get a handle to the `paper-button` element (The `ready()` function is called after everything, including after the element and its properties have been initialized, so it's a good time to query the local DOM).

```
ready() {
    super.ready(); // must call this for Polymer to work

    // get handle to paper-button element
    this._doneBtn = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('paper-button');
}
```

(**By the way**, I know using `this.$` can be used as a syntax short-cut for `Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector()` but that syntax only seems to work for targeting elements in the local DOM that have an `id`, e.g: `this.$.searchInput` will return a handle to the element with `id="searchInput"`. **Does anyone know of a shorthand for targeting non-id, regular elements without having to type `Polymer.dom(this.root)...`**?)

I have a function that detects `input` events on the search field. If there is a value in the search field, enable the button.

```
_onInput() {
    // if search input has value
    if (Boolean(this.$.searchInput.value)) {
        // remove disabled attr from button
        this._doneBtn.removeAttribute('disabled');
    } else {
        this._disableBtn();
    }
}

_disableBtn() {
    this._doneBtn.setAttribute('disabled', true);
}
```

Up to now, this works so that when a user starts typing, the button becomes enabled; when there is no value the button becomes disabled.

However, by convention, users can also delete the input value by clicking the little 'x' that appears on the right-hand-side of the search input. Developers can detect that event by attaching a `search` event to the input element:

```
ready() {
    super.ready(); // must call this for Polymer to work

    // get handle to paper-button element
    this._doneBtn = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('paper-button');

    // attach 'search' event listener to search input field
    // call the element's '_disableBtn' function
    this.$.searchInput.addEventListener('search', this._disableBtn);
}
```

**The problem is** when I trigger the event by clicking the 'x' that appears when the search field has a value, the `this._disableBtn` function fires, but `this._doneBtn` inside the function *returns undefined*:
[Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AxkO.png).

Assuming this might have to do with an improper type definition, I tried declaring the `_doneBtn` property in the Polymer properties getter:

```
static get properties() {
    return {
        _doneBtn: Object // also tried 'String'
    }
}
```

I also tried querying the DOM from inside the `_disabledBtn` function again and trying to re-declare the property but I still get the same error:

```
_disableBtn() {
    if (!this._doneBtn) {
        this._doneBtn = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('paper-button');
    }
    this._doneBtn.setAttribute('disabled', true);
}
```

Can anyone understand what's happening here? This seems to have something to do with the event listener. Perhaps the DOM is not fully rendered before it's parsed although switching the order of the declarations in the `ready()` call doesn't make a difference? It could also have something to do with `this`.

Interestingly, when I `console.log(this)` inside `_disableBtn`, the console returns two different `this` instances, one for the host element (`<app-search>`) and one for the target element that fired the event: [two elements point to 'this'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XHXd.png). Also noteworthy is the order that `this` is printed.

I'm hoping someone wiser than me can help solve what's going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading @softjake's response, I was able to solve the problem.

First, let's revisit the `addEventListener()` setup that was added in the `ready()` function:

```
ready() {
    super.ready();

    // handle to toggle button element
    this._doneBtn = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('paper-button');

    // previous method === no worky
    //this.$.searchInput.addEventListener('search', this._disableBtn);

    // changed it to:
    this.$.searchInput.addEventListener('search', this._disableBtn.bind(this._doneBtn));
}
```

The key here is that I'm using `.bind(this._doneBtn)` to make sure `this`, inside the scope of the `_disableBtn` function refers to `this._doneBtn` and not some other `this` (like the parent element or document/window).

Finally, adjust the `_disableBtn` function slightly:

```
_disableBtn() {
    // previous (also no worky)
    //this._doneBtn.setAttribute('disabled', true);

    // changed to:
    this.setAttribute('disabled', true);
}
```

Because `this` already refers to `this._doneBtn`, we can simply use `this.setAttribute(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

My gut feeling is that you don't use the "this" correctly. The "this" expresion is counter-intuitive as we tend to automatically associate it with the lexical scope or the location where the "this" is used. Alas, this is not the case as the "this" binding is not determine at JIT "compile time" nor a "runtime" but at "call time".

The this represents the context it was called from. So by simply moving a line of code from one function to another, the "this" could refer to something else. And that something else may not have a "setAttribute" function attached thus the "of undefined" error message.

One way to workaround this (no pun intended) reality is to configure the called function with a .bind([value we want "this" to have when calling that function]).

For instance, instead of writing the following snippet:

```
} else {
    this._disableBtn();
}
```

you would have writen

```
} else {
    this._disableBtn().bind(this);
}
```

You would have made shure that the "this" you use in the _disableBtn() function woud point to the same target as the "this" does in the "else" block.

Basically, the "this" value depends on the original call site context the function it is used in was called (I'm not sure if this is clear... but reread it slowly if it doesn't make sense on the first flight). To hardcode a value of "this" in the called function, you can add the .bind("this" value you want to pass to the called function) when calling the function such as:

```
function aFunction() {
   myfunction(parameter).bind("required value of 'this' in myFunction").
}
```

Hope this helps.

Jake

Comment: I think you're onto something. I just posted my solution. Thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: @Peak thanks, if it helps you with your problem, could you please put an up vote. Thanks.